# shared_ptr requires complete type; cannot use it with lua_State*

Tags: c++, boost, lua, shared-ptr

I'm writing a C++/OOP wrapper for Lua. My code is:

```
class LuaState
{
     boost::shared_ptr<lua_State> L;

     LuaState(): L( luaL_newstate(), LuaState::CustomDeleter )
     {
     }
}
```

The problem is lua_State is incomplete type and shared_ptr constructor requires complete type. And I need safe pointer sharing. (Funny thing boost docs say most functions do not require complete type, but constructor requires, so there is no way of using it. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

Can can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need safe pointer sharing, if I may ask. Can't you just call luaL_newstate in the constructor and lua_close in the destructor.

Comment: LuaState a, b;
a = b;
// lua_State in b will never be released
// lua_State in a will be released twice

The other option is cloning lua_State structure in copy constructor and operator=. But I suppose it is heavy solution.

Comment: You cannot clone lua_State structure manually. It will blow up in your face. I have tried it :)

Comment: That's what I thought. :) Well, what is solution for safe managing lua_State*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using your own deleter, which means that you don't have to have a complete type upon construction. The only requirement is that `CustomDeleter` can handle that. (it may convert the pointer passed to a complete type, for example (say, from `void*` to `CompleteType*`).

The background of completeness is that once the constructor of `shared_ptr` is called with the default deleter, it will instantiate a class that contains the line `delete p;` - and for this code to be correct, `p` must not be incomplete. The destructor will call this deleter code indirectly, so it doesn't depend on the completeness of the type.

However if you pass your own deleter, the requirements of your own deleter will apply. Be sure to define `CustomDeleter` after `lua_State` has become completed.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Your code is exactly what I wrote. It fails in "shared_ptr::checked_delete" at static check "typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];"

Comment: @topright, if you use your own deleter that does it right, it shouldn't fail like that. Be sure to define your `CustomDeleter` in such a way that its body occurs after the definition of `lua_State`.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed strange that `boost::shared_ptr` would require a complete type for instantiation, so I wrote this small little test that demonstrate the opposite (code at the end).

I believe that the problem is not with the type needing to be complete, but with the second argument that you are passing to the `shared_ptr` constructor, that looks like a member function. The second argument must be something callable with a single pointer argument. If you want to use a member function of your wrapper you can use `boost::bind` to adapt the interface.

Maybe you meant?:

```
 LuaState(): L( luaL_newstate(), boost::bind(LuaState::CustomDeleter,this,_1) )
 {
 }
```

Demonstration that `boost::shared_ptr` does not require complete types:

```
// forward declarations
struct test;
test * create();
void destroy(test *);

// wrapper equivalent to the one in the question
struct wrapper {
   boost::shared_ptr<test> sp;
   wrapper() : sp( create(), destroy ) {}
};

// actual definitions
struct test {};
test * create() { return new test; }
void destroy(test *t) { delete t; }

// make it executable
int main() {
   test t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that a lua_State* can't be cloned, is copying a LuaState object meaningful? What are the expected semantics of copying such an inherently uncopyable object?

The behaviour you seem to want is *shallow copying* - and the best way to do that is for LuaState to be uncopyable and manage the lifetime of the lua_State then you can pass around the state as a `shared_ptr<LuaState>`.